# Standard Deviation of Gaussian of Percentages

Tags: statistics

I understand how to calculate standard deviation using the formula: SQRT[SUM[(x_i-mu)^2/N]]

However, I only know how I can do this for a definite set of random numbers. I wish to find the SD of a Gaussian distribution where the x-axis is size and y-axis is percentage (Of total counts). I do not know the total number of counts though. I made a graph of the discrete data set I have here:

[Graph of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54tIk.png)

If I know the mean (mu) is about 65, but if I just input the discrete sizes into the formula it won't work since the sizes themselves are just bins, not the count. I thought that perhaps I could do a weighted calculation where I multiply each (w_i-mu)^2 value by the x_i's associative percentage, but apparently not since I get ~67 which is pretty much the mean, so I know that is not correct. I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: This is sample data, correct? Do you know the sample size? Also, are you looking to compute the variance or the standard deviation? The formula $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}(x_k-\mu)^2$ denotes the population variance

Comment: It´s not clear what the original problem is. Just post it.

Comment: @MatthewPilling This is sample data and I do not know sample size. I am looking for std deviation. Sorry, I miss-wrote the formula. Should have a square root.

Comment: @callculus This is not a formal problem, this is data I received from an instrument. I can try to ask in a different way. I wish to compute the standard deviation for a sample data set (Shown in the image). The issue is that the y-axis are percentages and the instrument does not tell me the total count so I have no idea of the count per size.

Comment: @Tom So your sample size is 100 now?

Comment: @callculus42 Yes. The way I came to that conclusion is summed up in my answer. Thank you for taking the time to look over the question and engage in a solution. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my initial assumption was correct, I just divided the total incorrectly. The total N, should be 100, not 14. This was because I thought I was dividing by the bin size. I realized that because this is a normalized distribution, the count/sample total is 100. So the correct formula for this would be as follows:

SQRT{SUM[((% Count)*(x_i-mu)^2)/100]}

By multiplying by the percent count for each bin (AKA the y-axis value associated with the x-axis value), this simplifies the problem so one does not need to sum over each of the same bin multiple times.